# Alternativa a New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql, azure-storage

Me encuentro trabajando en Microsoft Azure, en el cual tengo un grupo de recursos para un ambiente de pruebas y un ambiente de producción, en ambos tengo un servidor de base de datos de Azure SQL Databases con su respectiva base de datos.

Estoy creando un Runbook de Automation Accounts en Powershell en otra cuenta de Microsoft Azure (Nota importante) que se encarge de "Copiar" la base de datos de producción a pruebas, se que existe el comando New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy, sin embargo este comando no funciona con bases de datos "Hyperscale".

Existe alguna alternativa a este comando en Hyperscale? o bien en esta segunda cuenta es posible crear un .bacpac de forma remota con comandos de Azure para powershell, todos los que he visto son para trabajar en una misma cuenta pero la cuenta de las bases de datos es distinta a la de automation accounts debido a tas de trabajo.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda y comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

En estos momentos Database Copy no es soportado para Hyperscale, pero esta funcionalidad se encuentra actualmente en Private Preview. Se espera que en un par de meses esta funcionalidad este en "Public preview" y disponible en el portal de Azure.

Esta pregunta ya fue formulada en la versión en inglés de Stackoverflow como se puede apreciar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397933/alternative-to-new-azsqldatabasecopy-on-hyperscale-database).

Comment: Si, justamente la pregunta la hice yo en ambas comunidades.